# Convert 'yyyymmddhhmmss' to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM (AM/PM) in Snowflake

Tags: sql, string, date, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to convert a String containing values in the format `yyyymmddhhmmss` to `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM (AM or PM)` in Snowflake. The String contains time in UTC format. Also would like the final output to be in CST timezone.

> Eg of String : 20220120035900
>
> Expected output : 01/20/2022 03:59:00

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you [checked](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html) ?

Comment: I have tried `select to_timestamp_tz('20120225143620', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below  select try_to_timestamp('20220120035900', 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS');

[image]

UTC to CST:

```
SELECT try_to_timestamp('20220120035900', 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') as t_str,
    t_str::timestamp_ntz as UTC_tz,
    convert_timezone('UTC','America/Chicago', UTC_tz) chicago_time;
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. This time format is in UTC. Any way in which I can convert this to CST
Central Standard Time (CST) is 6 hours behind Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)

Comment: Great it works .. Please mark  as "Answer" so someone can use if needed.

Comment: Yes! Marked. Can you please let me know how I can convert the time in CST? The output is in UTC.

Comment: Added UTC to CST.